# ServletException When open my application

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, websphere, el

Iam using JSF 2.1 mojjara and primefaces 3.5 with WAS7 i complete the integration the FacesServlet is loaded from my JSF jar and the other component
the problem that iam facing seems now is the following :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've added the Mojarra 2.1 jars as a shared library in WAS 7, you'll get the baked-in WAS version (which I think is 1.2).  Then when you deploy the application you'll have to configure it to use that shared library.

Comment: Ian Thanks for the replay , the solution that i used to Make WAS 7 knows about my mojarra jars is by create shared library contains only the mojarra jar and primefaces jar and i think its work if you look at the stacktrace all needed faces class's are loaded from the mojjara not from the default jar (Myfaces 1.2)